# How to create an Array from the checked boxes

Tags: php, submit

I have 1000 checkboxes of object fields and I want to create an Array from all the fields that I check after submitting using PHP can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you name your checkbox like this, you already have an array:

```
<input name="mycheckbox[]" value="1"> hello1
<input name="mycheckbox[]" value="2"> hello2
<input name="mycheckbox[]" value="3"> hello3
```

in PHP you will get:

```
print_t($_REQUEST['mycheckbox']);
/*
[
   0 => '1',
   0 => '2',
   0 => '3'
]
*/
```

Comment: how to check whether it is checked or not?

Comment: @SouradipMandal only the checked ones will be sent to the server... if a checkbox is not checked, then it won't be part of the request

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" name="somename[]" value="somevalue">` if you need an array with numerical indices
or
`<input type="checkbox" name="someobject[property]" value="somevalue">` if you are looking for an associative array